# Z-index working incorrectly

Tags: css, z-index

I'm trying to have `#menuContainer` "above" `#mainOverlay` using the z-index property, but it won't work. My code for the two IDs:

**menuContainer**

```
#menuContainer{
    width:650px;
    height:50px;
    position:relative;

    z-index:2;

    margin-top:0;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-left:auto;

    background-color:rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.46);
}
```

**mainOverlay**

```
#mainOverlay{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    z-index:1;

    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Alternatively, you could check this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Whitevan_Candyman/p44R2/) out.

Reading similar questions didn't bear any fruits, so that's why I decided to ask a separate question, in case it won't work for other people in the same boat I am in.
All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/urfqs/ seems to work fine; what does your HTML look like for the two elements with respect to each other?

Comment: Maybe you try in IE? If so in which version? Cause in IE<= version RGBa colors are not supported.

Comment: You mean their parent/child listing stuff?

Comment: I am working in Chrome. I believe I'm using the latest version.

Comment: `menuContainer` does not belong to a parent, and has only child elements. `mainOverlay` is a child of `mainOverlayWrap`, which in turn doesn't have any parent elements itself. Putting `z-index:1` on `mainOverlayWrap` didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not in the same scope so the `z-index` will have no effect. You need to add the z-index on the same level, i.e to your parent element `#mainOverlayWrap` in your case. Remember you will also need to have `position: relative|absolute|fixed;` set for the z-index to have effect.

Comment: Adding `z-index` and `position:relative;` to `#mainOverlayWrap` didn't work.

Comment: I want `#menuContainer` to be "on top of" `#mainOverlayWrap`. To clarify it more specifically; If `#mainOverlayWrap` had `background-color:#000000;`, you would be able to see `#menuContainer`, if `#mainOverlayWrap` had `z-index:1;` and `#menuContainer` had `z-index:2;`.

Comment: Your fiddle is pretty much the solution to my problem, but for some reason it's not working for me.